# Configuration of Java Developer's Notebook

Tags: java, ide, hardware

For **Java** Platform, i use Eclipse Galileo IDE, Jboss Tools plugin, SpringSource IDE, MyEclipse IDE, Tomcat as Service, Mysql as Service, Oracle Sql Developer Client, Netbeans, Aptana Studio, also MonoDevelop etc. Which notebook configuration that i can use effectively ?

Comment: `notebook` tag removed as part of the [2012 cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 1):

One with lots of RAM - 4GB - and a 64-bit OS to take advantage of it.

Also a dual-core CPU, 2GHz per core or something.

(Then you just need a massive power supply, a separate keyboard and mouse and a big monitor :p )